# nodejs Async.each Nested loop Confusion

Tags: node.js, nested-loops, async.js

i want to have two nested for loops

```
async.each(ListA,
function(itemA,callback1){
        //process itemA
        async.each(itemA.Children,
        function(itemAChild,callback1){
              //process itemAChild  
              callback1();
               }),
    function(err){
    console.log("InnerLoopFinished")
    }   

callback();
}),function(err){
console.log("OuterLoopFinished")
}
console.log("Process Finished")
```

Now i expect an output Like 
{
InnerLoopFinished
OuterLoopFinished
} according to List Size and

process Finsished

Bt what i get is 
Process Finished at First
and InnerLoop and Outerloop message depending upon loop size..

Im process data in both loops so when control goes to print "final process" message i expect all my data is populated to an Object Before that and send it as a response which isnt achieved here

I think imnt not clear about idea of working async.each..Can someone help me to achieve the desired output

Comment: It is asynchronous. Asynchronous functions return immediately without waiting to process anything. That's why "Process Finished" is printed first. That's the whole point of callbacks and promises. They get called when the process finishes so that you can insert code to do what you want when that happens.

Comment: @slebetman so how can i solve my issue ? ... the single loop works fine in serial mode using asyn.each ... But for nested loop it doesnt work like i desired ....

Comment: First, you have a typo I think. You have two variables called `callback1` and none called `callback`

Comment: Also, I don't think your braces match. You seem to be missing some closing braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
async.each(ListA, function (itemA, callback) { //loop through array
    //process itemA
  async.each(itemA.Children, function (itemAChild, callback1) { //loop through array
    //process itemAChild
    callback1(); 
    }, function(err) {
      console.log("InnerLoopFinished");
      callback();
    });
  }, function(err) {
    console.log("OuterLoopFinished");
    console.log('Process Finished');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. was abt to post that i got solution by the same method u did .. Bit late ..bt thanks again  @mustafa