# async.each not processing mongoose find function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
    async.each(arrayUser, function (user, callback) { //loop through array
      console.log('1');
      async.each(user.parentOf, function (child, callback1) { //loop through array
        console.log(2);
        models.Students.find({
            '_id': child._id
          },
          function (err, foundStudent) {
            console.log('3');
            callback1();
          },
          function (err) {
            console.log("InnerLoopFinished");
            callback();
          });
      }, function (err) {
        console.log("OuterLoopFinished");
        console.log('Process Finished');
      });
    });
```

The arrayUser is created like this:

```
    var arrayUser = [];
    users.forEach(function (user) {
      var arrayUser1 = {
        parent: {
          _id: user._id,
          firstName: user.firstName,
          lastName: user.lastName
        },
        userRoleID: user.userRoleID.length,
        parentOf: user.parentOf

      };
      arrayUser.push(arrayUser1);
    });
```

and a sample of user.parentOf is:

```
    user.parentOf = [{
        studentLastName: 'Flores',
        studentFirstName: 'Aedan',
        studentID: 111444,
        _id: 5a596979ea2d7a360c75948c
      },
      {
        studentLastName: 'Moses',
        studentFirstName: 'Chase',
        studentID: 111756,
        _id: 5a596979ea2d7a360c759489
      }
    ]
```

My issue is that even with the `async.each` The function is still not running correctly. It seems to be hitting a wall when it gets to the `models.Students.find` function and it runs the next callback.

I need to run the InnerLoop completely before moving on to the next `user`.
I followed the correct answer at [nodejs Async.each Nested loop Confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823798/nodejs-async-each-nested-loop-confusion) 
but with no results. I have tried changing the `models.Students.find` function to `findOneAndUpdate` and I got the same result.

I think I need to add that I need to find multiple users with an inner array in each. If I had only one user (without the outer loop) it works fine.

my console.log is: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 ... 3, 3, 3...

and I need it to be 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we need to use async.eachSeries() instead of async.each(). This is the working snippet as per your expectation  1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3.

```
async.eachSeries(arrayUser, function (user, callback) { //loop through array
      console.log('1');
      async.eachSeries(user.parentOf, function (child, callback1) { //loop through array
        console.log(2);
        models.Students.find({
            '_id': child._id
          },
          function (err, foundStudent) {
            console.log('3');
            callback1();
          });
      },function (err) {
        console.log("InnerLoopFinished");
        callback();
      });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("OuterLoopFinished");
        console.log('Process Finished');
      });
    });
```

this is because the `eachSeries` function executes in iteratee function in order (after completion of the previous iteration and waits till `callback()` is called) so it gives output as per your expectation